# The User, The Myth, The Legend

Tags: discussion, users

User [Floris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26969/floris) has recently become the third user to obtain the [Legendary badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary), which is one of the less awarded badges out there. Being one of the most prolific contributors to this site, I just wanted to say thank you. Thank you for those amazing ~2.300 answers, thank you for the detailed yet intuitive explanations, for the fantastic diagrams, for taking the time to share knowledge, all in all, thank you for making this site a better place.

UPDATE (2017-12-05): As of today, Floris has become the fourth PSE user to become a member of the [100k club](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). Congratulations!

Comment: I remember when Floris just started out. Exponential growth is no joke! I've stopped leaving comments to change the colors in the matplotlib figures though, even though I can't see the defaults correctly!

Comment: How does someone have ~2.3 answers? Can't you round down and say 2? :D

Comment: I looked through Floris' questions and answers, and I see "Questions (1)" - I look, and it's self-answered. *::Jaw drops in awe::* Thanks for all you've done for this community!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I enjoy coming here and contributing, and your encouraging words hit a spot. This is a great community. Weird how some answers (like the recent Oreo cookie one) get a ton of upvotes, while others that I worked really hard on get hardly anything. But such is the network effect. @tpg2114 - I am sorry about the matplotlib defaults.  Could you leave another comment - I recently got a new computer and a different Python distribution (PyCharm instead of Canopy) ... maybe this time I will do it right.

Comment: @Floris That's always the way it seems.  The popular questions in terms of votes often aren't the most interesting physically.  They're usually the easily accessible questions.  It's a lot easier to do drive by upvotes if it's not a technical moshpit of topics that aren't as easily understood.

Comment: @Floris  I am now an occasional site visitor, but I would echo everything AFT says. Congrats and thanks.

Comment: @Floris What is really admirable is the honorable way you function; no unnecessary controversies, only quality  answers. Even your answers reflect the no-nonsense clear approach. You are exemplary, especially in view of the slew of controversial users in the past few years of this site. #respect

Comment: Florist should be congratulated for the incredible stamina displayed to reach the milestone.

Comment: @Floris Congrats on so many quality answers and the work involved, your answers are models of clarity, I was beginning to think you are the physics equivalent of [Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki), but I can tell a Floris answer after the first paragraph.

Comment: @Countto10 thank you very much! I got a smile out of that last sentence.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thank you. It's still fun...

Comment: @Floris (sorry for the typo above).  I’m amazed how some of you guys are dedicated.